# How to set multiple command into setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web site I want my page to scroll to the id of my interest.
I've found this nice code here on stackoverflow that does exactly what I need (I just made some little edits from the original)

```
var $scope, $location;
var headerHeigh = 50;
angular.module('allApps').service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){

    this.scrollTo = function(eID) {

        var startY = currentYPosition();
        var stopY = elmYPosition(eID)-headerHeigh;
        var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
        if (distance < 100) {
            scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
        }
        var speed = Math.round(distance / 50); 
        if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
        var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
        var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
        var timer = 0;

        if (stopY > startY) {
            for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer*speed);
                leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;

            } return;
        }
        for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
            setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
            leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
        }


        function currentYPosition() {
            // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
            // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
            if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
            return 0;
        }

        function elmYPosition(eID) {
            var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
            var y = elm.offsetTop;
            var node = elm;
            while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                node = node.offsetParent;
                y += node.offsetTop;
            } return y;
        }

    };

});

angular.module('allApps').controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $location, anchorSmoothScroll) {

    $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
      $location.hash(eID);
      anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);

    };
  });
```

My question is: why if I instead write this code

```
setTimeout(function(){
     window.scrollTo(0, leapY);
}, timer*speed);
```

I lose the "scrolling effect"?

The reason I would like to do this is because I want, together with the scrolling, some effect like a opacity changing while scrolling so I would like that into setTimeout there would be a function with more than one operation.

Thanks for helping

Comment: you need to increment `timer*speed` as well

Comment: Because `speed x 0` will always be 0?

Comment: I don't understand. If I write it like the original `setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer*speed);` it works. I can't see what's the difference

Comment: What's the link of the original code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code inside both for loops:

```
(function(leapY) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, leapY);
    }, timer*speed);
})(leapY);
```